# Menu not closing after clicking - Wordpress - Elementor

Tags: plugins, css

my primary menu isn't closing after clicking the link I wanted to visit.

[image: After clicking the link that I wanted to visit, redirects me to the page, but the dropdown menu stills there]

After clicking the link that I wanted to visit, redirects me to the page, but the dropdown menu stills there

I'm using Elementor for the menu. (The website was built like that, with Elementor & DIVI...) I'm not the developer, I'm only trying to fix bugs on the website.

Comment: Welcome to wpse! Going by the image alone it would be imposible to know why this happens, do some debugging, start with opening dev tools and looking at the console, most likely something will show up there, probably a wrong target or maybe you have a js error. You can also enable [WordPress debugging](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) if you think JS is not the culprit.

Comment: More to the point, third party themes are off topic.